# How to playing random value in audio array as many time as I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to play audio array list sequence but there are some conditions. The user would select dropdown for random questions and duration between each questions at first. And click play button to run.

When playIndex increments to 3, its duration starts relying on user's dropdown. But it gives me undefined now. But it's working when playIndex = 4. Why's this?

When playIndex increments to 8(after playing 7th element) and the amount of random questions is greater than 4, it will call random function to generate random values (number 4 to 7) for playIndex and play. But my code only does this once. Why's this??

I need to do as many time as the user want(dropdown 'numFollowUp') and minus 4 because in the first round, the code play from element 0 to 7, which I don't need to count the first 4 time(element 4 to 7).

After playing all random question, the playIndex should be

Please let me know if I confuse you. Thank you so much for your help.

```
<select id="numFollowUp" name="numFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Number of follow-up questions</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<select id="secFollowUp" name="secFollowUp" style=display:none>
            <option value="">Second between each question</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
</select>

$("#ImageEnterVariables").on("click", function() {
        $('#ImageEnterVariables').hide();
        $("#numFollowUp").show();
        $("#secFollowUp").show();
        $("#subBut").show();
        $("#pause").hide();
    });

var intro_playList = [{
          "duration": 11,        // in seconds, real file duration
          "key": "1_hello",     
          "delayAfter": 6,    // in seconds, delay after file ended
          "stage": "intro",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": false
        }, {
          "duration": 4,
          "key": "2_how_old",
          "delayAfter": 6,
          "stage": "intro",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": false
        }, {
          "duration": 3,
          "key": "3_what_did_you_make",
          "delayAfter": 10,
          "stage": "intro",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": false
        }, {
          // story_playlist
          "duration": 5,
          "key": "4_tell_me_a_story",
          "stage": "story",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": false
        }, {
          "duration": 4,
          "key": "5_and_then_what",
          "stage": "story",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": true
        }, {
          "duration": 2,
          "key": "6_why",
          "stage": "story",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": true
        }, {
          "duration": 3,
          "key": "7_tell_me_more",
          "stage": "story",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": true
        }, {
          "duration": 3,
          "key": "8_what_happened_next",
          "stage": "story",
          "runThrough": true,
          "random": true
        }, {
          "duration": 4,
          "key": "9_how_does_it_end",
          "stage": "ending",
          "runThrough": false,
          "random": false
        }, {
          "duration": 4,
          "key": "10_what_is_the_story_name",
          "stage": "ending",
          "runThrough": false,
          "random": false
        }, {
          "duration": 6,
          "key": "11_thank_you_goodbye",
          "stage": "ending",
          "runThrough": false,
          "random": false
        }];



$(document).ready(function() {
// Version 1
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio);

        var audioSrc = "sound/"
        var audioType = ".wav";
        var defaultNumFollowUp = 1; // default number of random question, if user this used the dropdown
        var defaultSecFollowUp = 10; // default delay (seconds) between random questions, if user this used the dropdown

        // Analyse the scenario by getting indexes in different arrays.
        var endingArr = [];
        var runThroughArr = [];
        var randomArr = [];

        for(i = 0; i < intro_playList.length ; i++){

            if(intro_playList[i].stage === "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
            if(intro_playList[i].runThrough){ runThroughArr.push(i); }
            if(intro_playList[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
        }

        function getAudio(n){
            audioElement.src = audioSrc + intro_playList[n].key + audioType;
            audioElement.load();
            audioElement.play();

            return intro_playList[n]; // return the object
        }

        // Onload indexes.
        var playIndex = 0;
        var randomplayCount = 0;
        var endingCount = 0;

        // Interval variables
        var playInterval;
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(time + " is old time");

        // User inputs
        var numFollowUp = parseInt($("#numFollowUp").val());
        if(isNaN(numFollowUp)){ numFollowUp = defaultNumFollowUp; }

        var secFollowUp = parseInt($("#secFollowUp").val());
        if(isNaN(secFollowUp)){ secFollowUp = defaultSecFollowUp; }

$("#play").on("click", playAudio);

function playAudio(){

            playInterval = setInterval(function(){ // Every 0.1 second, do setInterval
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                //console.log(now + " now time");

                if(now > time){
                    // First "run throught" plays all the audios in order, except the "ending" ones.
                    // playIndex = 0 in the first place
                    if(playIndex < runThroughArr.length){
                        var audioIndex = playIndex;
                        console.log("================================== RUN THROUGH!");
                        console.log("audioIndex is " + audioIndex);

                        playIndex++;

                    }else if (playIndex >= runThroughArr.length && randomplayCount <= numFollowUp){
                        var audioIndex = randomArr[ Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomArr.length - 1)) ];

                        console.log("================================== RUN random!");

                        // Increment index for next iteration
                        randomplayCount++;
                        console.log(randomplayCount);

                    }else if (randomplayCount >= defaultNumFollowUp && endingCount < endingArr.length ){
                        var audioIndex = endingArr[endingCount];

                        console.log("================================== RUN ending!");

                        // Increment index for next iteration
                        endingCount++;
                    }

                    // STOP INTERVAL!
                    if( endingCount === endingArr.length ){
                        clearInterval(playInterval);
                        console.log("=========== Interval stopped.");

                        // Reset onload indexes.
                        playIndex = 0;
                        randomplayCount = 0;
                        endingCount = 0;
                    }

                    // Prepare the audio file.
                    var audioObj = getAudio(audioIndex);

                    if(audioObj.stage === "intro"){
                    // set a new trigger time
                        time = new Date().getTime() + (audioObj.duration * 1000) + (audioObj.delayAfter * 1000);
                        console.log(time + " is time");

                    }else{

                        time = new Date().getTime() + (audioObj.duration * 1000) + (secFollowUp * 1000);
                    }

                    // Show what is actually playing
                    console.log("Playing "+ audioObj.key + " after " + audioObj.delayAfter + " seconds");
                    console.log("Stage: "+ audioObj.stage);

                } // if(now > time)

            }, 100); // playInterval, The interval duration of 0,1 second is to ensure accuracy if you set a duration or "delayAfter" using float seconds like 2.5.

        } // playAudio

        // Preload all audios to make sure they are available since timing is sometimes short.
        var preloadArr = [];

        for(i = 0; i < intro_playList.length; i++){

            var audioElementPreload = document.createElement('audio');
            audioElementPreload.src = audioSrc + intro_playList[i].key + audioType;
            audioElementPreload.load();
            preloadArr.push(audioElementPreload);
        }
});
```

Comment: Not following logic. What is the expected order of playback?

Comment: Thank you replying sir. So, it will play from the beginning (element 0) until element 8, ( the first round). At this point, i will become 9 and start randomly playing array list between element 5 to 8 depending on how many times the user want (the variable 'numFollowUp' ). If you still aren't sure what I'm saying, please let me know.

Comment: _"depending on how many times the user want (the variable 'numFollowUp' )"_ What are the other possibilities?

Comment: What is `var userSecInput = $("#secFollowUp").val();` ?

Comment: I'm so sorry guys. I have edited the post again. Please take a look about the user's selection. Please let me know if you are still confused.

Comment: Where is `playAudio` defined?

Comment: Do you mean, var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');  , or   audioElement.play() ??

Comment: Ok, found the function declaration for `playAudio` in the code. What is issue with the code at Question?

Comment: So I want that if the user chooses some selection(variable 'numFollowUp') at first, let's say 8, then my program will play audio from the element 0 until element 8 after the click (play button). And then start randomly choosing between element 5 to 8 four times because I have played from the element from 5 to 8 when index increments to 9 in the first round, so it's 4 left. This 4 left times will always be randomly. After this four times, my program will play from the element 9 to the end of array.

Comment: My problem is my program will do this once and then the index goes to the 10th element. It doesn't do the rest of 3 times (as the example I gave). It is hard to explain this in word. I'm truly sorry.

Comment: On my side, I think I get the play sequence... I think... Ho, I just wrote brand new code since yours isn't talking to me. What I don't get at this point, is the "duration" factor. Is it the audio file length? Is it a delay between each file play... Is the audio simply a voice saying a short question like the "key" suggests?

Comment: So it is defined by the `intro_playList` duration property on first run throught... And then by user selection of the second dropdown? Or always one or the other...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette duration is the delay between each file play. All of audio files are just simply some voice asking short questions. Like the third element is just simply asking, "How are you?"   I want to play randomly when the index increments to 9. Please let me know if you have further questions. Thank you so much. and sorry this is hard to explain

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Well, the program runs the first four elements of duration defined in array. After that, it will run by user selection of the second dropdown. The reason I set all 1000 after the first four elements because if I don't define something in the array for duration property, the program would give me error

Comment: So that is the user selection you prefer the script to use...

Comment: From the 'tell_me_a_story' element, it will be user's selection dropdown (variable 'secFollowUp') . Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You are getting the user inputs on load... `numFollowUp` and `secFollowUp` ALWAYS are setted to the default values because the user just didn't had time to select. That is why those `isNaN` condition have to be in `playAudio` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully rewrote your code from scratch... *A second time!*
I think that really is a nice project... And a nice coding challenge.

On this second taught, I saw a couple issues in the first delaying "concept" using `setTimeout()`:

1. Audio lenghts longer than the timeout delay were cutted... Leaving no  timeout between the two files.
2. Even if the audio wasn't longer than the delay, this delay was partially "absorbed" by the file length.
3. Changing the "scenario", like by adding more random questions, needed tweeks in the code.
4. The "ending" to be played after the random "stage" needed nested `setTimeout()` for each ending file, which is horrible.

So I thought that to use `setInterval()` to check the "actual time" compared to the time the script sets to start the next audio (based on file duration + delay) at each iteration... Would be an idea.

**And it works!** It simplified the code quite a lot.
And all "scenario" infos are now in the object array.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GvyNqa?editors=1011)

```
var audioSrc = "https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/45704602/";    // Path to the audio files
var audioType = ".mp3";

var default_numFollowUp = 4;  // default number of random question, if user this used the dropdown
var default_secFollowUp = 10;  // default delai (seconds) between random questions, if user this used the dropdown

// Create the audio element
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

// Analyse the scenario by getting indexes in different arrays.
var endingArr = [];
var runThoughArr = [];
var randomArr = [];
for(i=0;i<intro_playList.length;i++){
  if(intro_playList[i].stage == "ending"){ endingArr.push(i); }
  if(intro_playList[i].runThough){ runThoughArr.push(i); }
  if(intro_playList[i].random){ randomArr.push(i); }
}

// Get an audio and play it
function getAudio(n){
  audioElement.src = audioSrc + intro_playList[n].key + audioType;
  audioElement.load();
  audioElement.play();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(intro_playList[n]));
  return intro_playList[n]; // return the object
}

// Onload indexes.
var playIndex = 0;
var randomplayCount = 0;
var endingCount = 0;

// Interval variables
var playInterval;
var time = new Date().getTime();


// Function to start the interval check to play a file
function playAudio(){

  // User inputs
  var numFollowUp = parseInt($("#numFollowUp").val() );
  if(isNaN(numFollowUp)){ numFollowUp = default_numFollowUp;}

  var secFollowUp = parseInt($("#secFollowUp").val() );
  if(isNaN(secFollowUp)){  secFollowUp = default_secFollowUp; }

  // Ensure no other interval runs...
  clearInterval(playInterval);

  // Set the interval.
  playInterval = setInterval(function(){

    var now = new Date().getTime();
    if(now > time){

      // First "run throught" plays all the audios in order, except the "ending" ones.
      if( playIndex < runThoughArr.length){
        var audioIndex = playIndex;
        console.log("==================================================================== RUN TROUGH!");

        // Increment index for next iteration
        playIndex++;
      }

      // Random!
      else if( playIndex >= runThoughArr.length && randomplayCount < numFollowUp ){
        //var audioIndex = getRandomIndex();
        var audioIndex = randomArr[ Math.floor(Math.random()*(randomArr.length-1)) ];
        console.log("==================================================================== RANDOM! ("+randomplayCount+"/"+numFollowUp+")");

        // Increment index for next iteration
        randomplayCount++;
      }

      // Ending
      else if( randomplayCount >= numFollowUp && endingCount < endingArr.length ){
        var audioIndex = endingArr[endingCount];
        console.log("==================================================================== ENDING!");

        // Increment index for next iteration
        endingCount++;
      }

      // STOP INTERVAL!
      if( endingCount == endingArr.length ){
        clearInterval(playInterval);
        console.log("=========== Interval stopped.");

        // Reset onload indexes.
        playIndex = 0;
        randomplayCount = 0;
        endingCount = 0;
      }

      // Prepare the audio file.
      var audioObj = getAudio(audioIndex);

      if(audioObj.stage == "intro"){
        // set a new trigger time
        time = new Date().getTime() + (audioObj.duration * 1000) + (audioObj.delayAfter * 1000);
      }else{
        time = new Date().getTime() + (audioObj.duration * 1000) + (secFollowUp * 1000);
      }
      // Show what is actually playing
      console.log("Playing "+ audioObj.key);
      console.log("Stage: "+ audioObj.stage);

    } // if(now > time)

  },100); // interval

} // playAudio()

// Preload all audios to make sure they are available since timing is sometimes short.
var preloadArr = [];
for(i=0;i<intro_playList.length;i++){
  var audioElementPreload = document.createElement('audio');
  audioElementPreload.src = audioSrc + intro_playList[i].key + audioType;
  audioElementPreload.load();
  preloadArr.push(audioElementPreload);
}

// Play button handler
$("#play").on("click", playAudio);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I will test it out and let you know. This is really challenging to me :( This project actually running on the mobile, so if I host a web, hopefully it will run perfectly on the mobile

Comment: It should run correctly on mobiles too... But I didn't test it.

Comment: At first, I did everything with API, but I didn't know API couldn't run iOS and Android. So I spent 1 month on nothing. And I decided to run this in pure JavaScript. Hopefully it will work fine on mobile phone

Comment: Sir, there are some parts I don't understand. What does duration mean in the array? You comment as "real file duration", does that mean the length of the element? In my case, I don't have silence audio anymore and my hello audio has 11 seconds, sometimes it cuts the last two seconds and play the How_old audio directly. And It should wait for 6 seconds but it doesn't.

Comment: *«What does duration mean in the array?»* : That is the audio FILE real duration, in seconds (can be a float number). --- `"delayAfter"` (integer) should be your 6 seconds after. --- I will make an "intro" audio file of more than 10 seconds and update the CodePen... *For fun.*

Comment: I made a "[real use case test](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/wqmwNB?editors=1011)".

Comment: Brilliant. You are really smart. I am still trying to figure out some parts of your suggestion and testing. I do have a question, why is your setInterval duration 100? That means every 0.1 second, you call this function for what? The interesting part is I made 2 for numFollowUp, but only randomly choosing and playing once?

Comment: The interval duration of 0,1 second is to ensure accuracy if you set a duration or "delayAfter" using float seconds like 2.5. Also... The file length probably doesn't fit round seconds... So this accuracy is needed.  --- In my demo, I get the correct amount of random plays... So I don't know what you may have changed.

Comment: I'm still testing for my case :) But you are really genius. This might be an extra question, but do you think I can get your email or other contact info so that I can ask you more questions and you can teach me more other than in here?

Comment: That all is in my SO profile. Look for my website for email, Skype, etc...

Comment: Sir, I just re-edit the post. Everything works fine except the random choosing part that it only chooses once. I thought it's because of the if statement but the if statement looks fine. Do you know what happened?

Comment: Brilliant, it works!! I have learned a lot from your suggestion. Thank you so much. Here's a quick question. So everything is working right now. But after playing the last audio in the array, it tries to play every audio from the beginning again. I try to stop this until the user clicks the play button again so I put 'audioElement.currentTime = 0;' inside of if( endingCount === endingArr.length ), but it doesn't work. Can you teach me why??

Comment: That is `clearInterval(playInterval);` that stops the interval. You should see `=========== Interval stopped.` in console **while** the last ending audio is playing.

Comment: Yea, even if I did clearInterval(playInterval); , it still plays from the beginning. This is weird

Comment: okay... Maybe there is more than one interval running... If you double clicked on play or whatever... That is a possibility. --- Before `playInterval = setInterval(function(){`, add `clearInterval(playInterval);`. It will ensure only one interval.

Comment: I just tested it. It's the same thing. I'm sure I click only once on play. Do you think it's possible to have more than two interval running? Even if it does, clearInterval(playInterval) should reduce into only once interval, right?

Comment: That was a guess... So now I sure that's not it. I always check that before since I lost days in finding that kind of issue ;) Now, check the `endingCount` and `endingArr.length` with console.log()...

Comment: I feel you :) Well, that's even weirder, ended function does play entire array, it should stop once it's done, and the code doesn't have two intervals running. Where's the problem?

Comment: The only trick is to look what you variables are... Like try to console log `n` in `getAudio(n)`. It takes patience! ;)

Comment: This is weird, sir. I looked up the n in getAudio(n). After playing the last audio in the array, n = 10, I set if n = 10, clearInterval(playInterval). But it still plays from the beginning. Also, I looked up the value of playInterval in if( endingCount === endingArr.length ), the value is 7. I set if(playInterval === 7), do clearInterval, but it's still not working :(

Comment: Copy all your code as it is right now in [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) and give me the link... I will check it.

Comment: Please take a look at it. Thank you so much. https://pastebin.com/54zd9GWd

Comment: Make it public (the pastebin)... It actually is "private".

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice it.

Comment: remove `audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playAudio);` Simple as this. The script works using the time checked with the interval. No more need for the `ended` event. That is what was restarting the play...

Comment: And dont forget to remove `clearInterval(playInterval);` (line #182 of your pastebin) which was a test... And change `var playIndex = 0;` from 10 to 0. ;)

Comment: Ohhhh I see. So we are doing script with index and interval so we don't need to ended event. But would you mind explaining when we need ended event? I have searched many stackoverflows, people say if you want to play entire array list, you should use ended event.  Another question I have for you is, I'm still not sure why we need to do preload at the end? Does this mean before we play audio, it will make sure if every audio is valid?  Thank you for answering all my questions. I really learn a lot from you :)

Comment: The ended event is usefull... But not in this script. You wanted an additional delay after a file ended, and not always the same. --- The preload occurs on page load... And it ensures the will not be an additional delay loading the file from the server. So when it's time to play the file, it already has been downloaded and is in the browser cache, ready to play.

Comment: Sir, I just tested this with my smart phone... it doesn't play audio. Do you have any idea why? Here's the link. https://johnny00520.github.io/Test.git.io/

Comment: I just came across another question about audio on mobile.
It was about "autoplay"... 
I knew "autoplay" on page load was prevented on mobiles, but not how and why.
What I found is that the audio (or video) play must be a **direct** result of a user action, like a click, a mouseover, etc.

I think the only alternative is to show a message asking the user to click somewhere to trigger the audio.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I also read about that you need a user action which is what I did for the play button. My code in the first place was fine to play audio. Where do you think it's the problem

Comment: There was a click to start the interval... But an interval executes a function at a given time interval... This function isn't the **direct** result of the initial click. Now how does the browser figures that out is the question. It is related to something in the event object, which doesn't follows in the interval function anyway.

Comment: Well, If I didn't misunderstand what you meant, I shouldn't have a timeInterval after the user click play button? I made a new pastebin, please take a look when you have time. https://pastebin.com/54zd9GWd

Comment: Sure I will... And no, I wasn't saying that the interval is the problem. You would have had the same problem with the setTimeouts. The problem is the original click event not present...

Comment: So you mean because I set up the count variable for 14 seconds after click the play, so the click isn't the one that triggers audio?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but that is what I understood from my reading. I think the trick for mobiles would be to show a button at each "play time".

Comment: I see what you mean. But I need to do only once play button, and play what we have coded. Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think so... And If so, I don't know how. You are asking how to walk around a browser intended limitation which a lot of people would like to override... And from what I know, no one found. I really think the only thing you can do -- but only on mobiles -- is to show a beautifull play button when it's time to play a file, after the "delayAfter" has passed.

Comment: A beautiful button? :) Well, actually, the target for this web app is children and I don't want let children to see a screen because a screen would distract them. So I'm thinking to turn on this app and put it in a doll and play all audios just like what you coded. This is a really sad news that it can't work on the mobiles

Comment: I may have a weird idea to try. But we should better talk on Skype. Click on the Skype link at the bottom of my [website](https://www.bessetteweb.com).

Comment: Yea, sounds good. I'm still not home yet. I probably need 1 and half or 2 hours more. Is that too late for you, sir?

Comment: I will possibly be sleeping... But that is not a problem... We'll be able to continue to text chat like here.

Comment: I just send you message thru Facebook

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `.queue()` , `.promise()`, `.then()` and repeated scheduling to perform an action on a full array, `while` loop `.splice()` and `.splice()` with `Math.random()` and `Math.floor()` to get N elements of the original array as a new array, select a pseudo random element from the sliced array, repeat original task, then repeat task using original array to conclude procedure.

```js
var arr = [...Array(9).keys()],
  currentRandomTracks = [],
  notify = function notify(message) {
   $("body").append(message + "<br>")
  }
  
var player = $({});

function playTracks(tracks) {
  return player.queue("tracks", $.map(tracks, function(el, index) {
    return function(next) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // do stuff 
        setTimeout(function() {
          resolve(el);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 750))
      }).then(function(value) {
        notify(value);
        // call `next` when synchronous or asynchronous task completes
        return next()
      })
    }
  })).dequeue("tracks").promise("tracks")
}

function handleRandomQueue() {
    // select N elements from `arr`
    if (currentRandomTracks.length === 0) {
      currentRandomTracks = arr.slice(6);
      var randomTracks = [];
      // select random elements from `currentRandomTracks`
      while (currentRandomTracks.length) {
        randomTracks[randomTracks.length] = currentRandomTracks
          .splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * currentRandomTracks.length), 1)
          .pop();
      }
      notify("original playlist done playing, "
        + "starting playing random indexes " 
        + currentRandomTracks.toString() + " next"
      );
      return playTracks(randomTracks)
    } else {
      notify("random playback playlist complete, "
        + "stating playing original playlist " 
        + arr.toString()
      );
      // perform task on original array, again
      return playTracks(arr);
    }
  }
  
  function handleRepeatOriginalQueue() {
    notify("original and random playlist playback complete");
    return playTracks(arr);
  }
  
  function handleQueueComplete() {
    // procedure complete
    notify("original, random, "
      + "and second original playlist playback complete"
    );
  }

$(function() {

playTracks(arr)
  .then(handleRandomQueue)
  .then(handleRepeatOriginalQueue)
  .then(handleQueueComplete)
  .fail(function err(err) {
    console.error(err)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body></body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. You code is really professional so I need to spend time to figure out. Just let you know that I need to start randomly playing audios from the element 5 to 8 after the first looping playing the audio array (element 0 to 8).

Comment: @Johnny Arrays are zero based indexed. An array having `.length` `9` will have indexes 0-8. At stacksnippets `.slice()` is called with `6` as parameter, returning indexes 6, 7, 8. If indexes expected are 5, 6, 7 you can call `.slice()` with parameters `5` and `-1` `arr.slice(5, -1)`

Comment: I think I got the idea. I will try it tomorrow and I will let u you know I have further questions. Thank you sir

Comment: @Johnny See updated post. Was missing second parameter to `.splice()`